# Why do I get "NoSuchMethodException" & "IOException upon attempt to marshall", error?

Tags: coldfusion, logging

I am seeing a very large number of the errors below in my log files. Nothing *seems* to be causing them in the way that none of our users are seeing any errors. What could be causing them? We are running CF 8.

FYI: They are happening many times per second.

```
12/11 12:30:13 error jrunx.scheduler.SchedulerService.cancel()
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jrunx.scheduler.SchedulerService.cancel()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at jrunx.rmi.RMIBroker.invokeService(RMIBroker.java:280)
    at jrunx.rmi.RMIBroker.invoke(RMIBroker.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

IOException upon attempt to marshall 0 argument of type jrun.servlet.session.SessionHolder.
12/11 12:30:13 error 
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy2.cancel(Unknown Source)
    at jrunx.kernel.ServiceAdapter.unscheduleRunnable(ServiceAdapter.java:760)
    at jrun.servlet.session.SessionService.unscheduleRunnable(SessionService.java:1019)
    at jrun.servlet.session.SessionHolder.reschedule(SessionHolder.java:148)
    at jrun.servlet.session.JRunSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(JRunSession.java:135)
    at jrun.servlet.session.SessionService.createSession(SessionService.java:1250)
    at jrun.servlet.ForwardRequest.getSession(ForwardRequest.java:384)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppHelper.setupJ2eeSessionScope(AppHelper.java:521)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppHelper.setupSessionScope(AppHelper.java:592)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.ApplicationTag.doStartTag(ApplicationTag.java:279)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)
    at cfApplication2ecfm428394136.runPage(D:\WEB\ROOT\wwwdev4\bs\worklife\Application.cfm:3)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:388)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.include(CfincludeFilter.java:33)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:221)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:86)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:74)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:198)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jrunx.scheduler.SchedulerService.cancel()
    at jrunx.cluster.ClusterAlgorithm.invokeService(ClusterAlgorithm.java:127)
    at jrunx.cluster.ClusterAlgorithm.invokeService(ClusterAlgorithm.java:80)
    at jrunx.rmi.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:304)
    at jrunx.rmi.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:183)
    at jrunx.rmi.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:160)
    ... 42 more

12/11 12:30:13 error jrunx.scheduler.SchedulerService.scheduleFromNow()
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jrunx.scheduler.SchedulerService.scheduleFromNow()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at jrunx.rmi.RMIBroker.invokeService(RMIBroker.java:280)
    at jrunx.rmi.RMIBroker.invoke(RMIBroker.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

IOException upon attempt to marshall 0 argument of type jrun.servlet.session.SessionHolder.
12/11 12:30:13 error 
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy2.scheduleFromNow(Unknown Source)
    at jrunx.kernel.ServiceAdapter.scheduleRunnable(ServiceAdapter.java:739)
    at jrun.servlet.session.SessionService.scheduleRunnable(SessionService.java:1007)
    at jrun.servlet.session.SessionHolder.reschedule(SessionHolder.java:167)
    at jrun.servlet.session.JRunSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(JRunSession.java:135)
    at jrun.servlet.session.SessionService.createSession(SessionService.java:1250)
    at jrun.servlet.ForwardRequest.getSession(ForwardRequest.java:384)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppHelper.setupJ2eeSessionScope(AppHelper.java:521)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppHelper.setupSessionScope(AppHelper.java:592)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.ApplicationTag.doStartTag(ApplicationTag.java:279)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)
    at cfApplication2ecfm428394136.runPage(D:\WEB\ROOT\wwwdev4\bs\worklife\Application.cfm:3)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:388)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.include(CfincludeFilter.java:33)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:221)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:86)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:74)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:198)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jrunx.scheduler.SchedulerService.scheduleFromNow()
    at jrunx.cluster.ClusterAlgorithm.invokeService(ClusterAlgorithm.java:127)
    at jrunx.cluster.ClusterAlgorithm.invokeService(ClusterAlgorithm.java:80)
    at jrunx.rmi.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:304)
    at jrunx.rmi.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:183)
    at jrunx.rmi.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:160)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: Do you have any CF Scheduled Tasks set up? Are they all working properly? Do any of them have repeating duration of seconds?

Comment: can you post your Application.cfm?  Can you post your settings from the Memory Variables page in CFAdmin?  And by any chance do you have Memory Tracking turned on in server monitor?

Comment: We are in a shared environment. Yes there are CF Scheduled tasks but I do not have access to the Administrator pages so I can't check these things. If there are things I should ask my admins, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, ask about the scheduled tasks and/or other services that might be running repeatedly.

Comment: Is there any way for me to programmatically see the results of scheduled tasks?

Comment: I am a C# developer so I probably can't add too much help, but I would immediately question whether the client has the correct version of the (dll?) on their side. I have seen this type of thing in .NET before. It was due to a dll with different code but the dll version information was not updated before shipping. The system then uses the out of date dll because the version information of the new file is the same as the old file so it uses the old file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by J2EE session variables being enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Did the error start occuring after an upgrade  ?

Maybe [zipscan](http://www.foobarsoftware.com/) the constituent JARs,WARs, EARs on your system for the class 'jrunx.scheduler.SchedulerService' - and see if you have multiple copies of it. [ esp. something like a JAR 'hidden' inside a WAR or something, which could have been build with an earlier version of the class].

The Java Stack suggested that the method 'cancel()' is expected by the calling class, but that method doesn't exist - suggesting that maybe it used to on an old version.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jrunx.scheduler.SchedulerService.cancel()
```